# How to fill a queue and also print it at the same time?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am currently filling a queue system with messages. A separate thread should be printing the queue as the new messages start coming in. The problem is my program is not working.

```
private static void pData(IWebDriver driver)
{
    Queue<string> messageToSend = new Queue<string>();

    Thread printThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(PrintQueueMessages));
    printThread.Start(messageToSend);

    while (true)
    {
        messageToSend.Enqueue(GetLastElement(driver).Text));
    }
}

private static void PrintQueueMessages(object messageQueue)
{
    //Wont let me cast messageQueue as queue. 
}
```

I just want a simple and clean way to print my queue as my while loop fills my queue. Also, the queue system should keep waiting for message, it should never stop waiting for messages and printing them.

Please note: The queue system should be working on its own time. As message come in, it should print.

Comment: I am voting to reopen, the problem space is defined, the end goal is specified, code was included.

Comment: @00110001 Thank you very much. I greatly disagree with why it was closed.

Comment: To have the best chance of this being reopened. try to format the question a little better, format the code, and explain a little more about what you are trying to do

Comment: @00110001 I appreciate the advice. Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered using a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_BlockingCollectionT) instead of a `Queue<T>`?

Comment: Btw `messageToSend` is a poor name for a `Queue<string>`. This name would be suitable for an element stored in the queue, not for the queue as a whole. A better name would be, for example, `messageQueue`.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to suggest a completely different approach, rather than a BCL Queue, (in this instance) an [Unbounded Channel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/) would be a nice fit

The advantages are

- You don't have to synchronize a queue and workloads and perpetual while loop to work in a multi threaded environment.
- It is extremely optimized and light weight
- It will deal with multiple threads
- It's cancellable
- It's completable
- and it uses (and will work well with) the *async and await pattern* and *IO workloads*.

**Given**

```
private static Channel<string> _channel;

public static async Task ReaderAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   // read from the channel until complete
   await foreach (var message in _channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync(cancellationToken))
      Console.WriteLine("New message : " + message);

   Console.WriteLine("Finished");
}
```

**Test**

```
var ts = new CancellationTokenSource();

_channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();

// start the reader task
var task = ReaderAsync(ts.Token);

// post some junk to the channel, this can be on a different thread
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   // some delay for the fun of it
   await Task.Delay(10, ts.Token);
   // write to the channel
   await _channel.Writer.WriteAsync(i.ToString(), ts.Token);
}

 // complete it when and if you are finished
_channel.Writer.Complete();

// just awaiting completion for this demo
await task;

Console.WriteLine("Game over");
```

**Output**

```
New message : 0
New message : 1
New message : 2
New message : 3
New message : 4
New message : 5
New message : 6
New message : 7
New message : 8
New message : 9
Finished
Game over
```

Comment: Im quite confused. I want to keep loading messages inside the channel. A for loop would not work. Could you please fix it towards my functions?